# Why does xcode open when debugging Flutter projects?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I updated my phone to iOS 17 and I'm using Xcode 15. After the update, Xcode started to open automatically when I debug the flutter project. Before, we used to run Xcode ourselves if necessary, but now it runs continuously and the debug session is open on Xcode. When I close Xcode, the debug session is also closed. Unnecessary ram and resource consumption.

Why does Xcode open while debugging flutter projects now, is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Also kills the process when the computer sleeps, really sucky new behavior.

Comment: Same issue, I upgraded to ios 17 and xcode 15 and now this happens.

Comment: any solution for this please advise

Answer (score 5):

As explained [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/native-debugging): If your app imports iOS platform-specific libraries, then Xcode is needed to debug that portion of your code. Xcode running in the foreground is expected behaviour until Apple (hopefully) adds a missing debugging feature for iOS 17.

Flutter used to silently build your project using Xcode and then launch a `debugserver` on the iOS device using `ios-deploy`. iOS 17 no longer supports `ios-deploy` however, and the replacement tooling in Xcode 15 is not able to start a `debugserver` as required by Flutter. Apple now only allows Xcode 15 running in the foreground to start a `debugserver` on iOS 17 and newer. (source: [Flutter issue #133465](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133465))

Debugging your app in Flutter web on the other hand doesn’t require Xcode to run, and will quickly highlight any incompatible iOS libraries.

Comment: Can you clarify your "full stop" comment? Is this specific behavior new with Xcode 15 and/or iOS 17?

I ask because I've been debugging my app (which does include an iOS platform-specific library) from within VS Code on Mac using Xcode 14.3 / iOS 16.x for a couple of months without ever seeing Xcode. All the app's log messages went to the VS Code debug console, etc.

Now, on a brand new Mac running Sonoma, with Xcode 15.0.1 and targeting iOS 17.x, I'm getting the behavior described in this question.

So it may be "full stop" behavior. But if it is, it's new with this updated environment.

Comment: I updated my answer. The new behavior is expected due to breaking changes in iOS 17 and the lack of a key feature in Apple's new debug tooling in Xcode 15.